# Create Button on every touch on screen

Tags: android, button, touch

I want to make an application where whenever I touch the screen, which should be blank at the start, a button will be created and pop up onto the screen. So what I tried here is to make a button in main.xml and call it by id. Then I applied this method.

```
public class TouchButtonActivity extends Activity {
Button b;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b.setOnTouchListener(nextListener);
}


public OnTouchListener nextListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            float x = event.getX()*event.getXPrecision();
            float y = event.getY()*event.getYPrecision();
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams p = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            p.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
            p.leftMargin = (int) x;
            p.topMargin = (int) y;
            b.setLayoutParams(p);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

}
```

This my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
 >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="B" />

</FrameLayout>
```

How could i do this?

Comment: [This](http://www.droidnova.com/2d-tutorial-series-part-iv,833.html) may be give some clues for you.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to add a button while you click any where in the screen i think you can use a Relative layout and add touch listener on that layout. While touching on that screen, add button on that layout so it will be like on new touch a new button will be popped up. Thank you

Codes will be like --

> Main Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rl"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
```

And the class will be like --

```
rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
    rl.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            float x = event.getX()*event.getXPrecision();
            float y = event.getY()*event.getYPrecision();

            Button btn = new Button(getApplicationContext());
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams bp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            bp.leftMargin = (int) x;
            bp.topMargin = (int) y;
            btn.setLayoutParams(bp);
            rl.addView(btn);

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but:

1) Make sure that your `main.xml` layout is `FrameLayout`

2) And then change your code:

```
public OnTouchListener nextListener = new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    float x = event.getX()*event.getXPrecision();
                    float y = event.getY()*event.getYPrecision();
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams p = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    p.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
                    p.leftMargin = (int) x;
                    p.topMargin = (int) y;
                    b.setLayoutParams(p);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
```

**EDIT**

You forgot this:

```
setOnTouchListener(nextListener);
```

Comment: @MBMJ make sure that `onTouch` is called. Otherwise - provide full code in your question.

Comment: it still the same.look what i want is if i touch any place of the screen a button will show.How many times the screen is touch ,this amount of button will show

Comment: do you have any idea about it?

Comment: @MBMJ make sure that `onTouch` is getting called and your layout is `FrameLayout`.

Comment: my layout is frame layout and look at my edited post.Here you see that i called the onTouch method.

Comment: @MBMJ sorry, my mistake. Not `b.setOnTouchListener`. Just `setOnTouchListener` to your `FrameLayout`.

Comment: please look my xml file i added.Tell me where i need to add this setOnTouch?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16010/discussion-between-biovamp-and-mbmj)